# Validating Date Time in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

The below code returns "TRUE" if the input is valid but throws an error if the input is wrong. For example, if the month value is given as 15, it throws error. How could I return false instead of an error/exception ?

```
<xsl:template match="SUBSCRIBER">
    <xsl:variable name="date-iso" select="dm:stringToDateTime('20130327230844')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="($date-iso castable as xs:dateTime)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="dm:stringToDateTime">
    <!-- Convert string to date. Input format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, Ex:20130116100037  -->
    <xsl:param name="p_str" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime(concat(substring($p_str,0,5),'-',substring($p_str,5,2),'-',substring($p_str,7,2),'T',substring($p_str,9,2),':',substring($p_str,11,2),':',substring($p_str,13,2)))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your attempt to use the `xs:dateTime` constructor in `xs:dateTime(concat(substring($p_str,0,5),'-',substring($p_str,5,2),'-',substring($p_str,7,2),'T',substring($p_str,9,2),':',substring($p_str,11,2),':',substring($p_str,13,2)))` will cause an error if the string you construct is not an `xs:dateTime`. You need to change the function code, if it is possible that the input format is not a valid `xs:dateTime` then in the function don't try to construct on, only return the string with

```
<xsl:function name="dm:stringToDateTime">
    <!-- Convert string to date. Input format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, Ex:20130116100037  -->
    <xsl:param name="p_str" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="concat(substring($p_str,1,4),'-',substring($p_str,5,2),'-',substring($p_str,7,2),'T',substring($p_str,9,2),':',substring($p_str,11,2),':',substring($p_str,13,2))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

then check

```
<xsl:template match="SUBSCRIBER">
    <xsl:variable name="date-iso" select="dm:stringToDateTime('20130327230844')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="($date-iso castable as xs:dateTime)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course it might be better to rename the function or alternatively write a second one doing the castable check.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea by using "castable as" but you need to do this before attempting the cast, not after. Something like

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" select="concat(substring($p_str,0,5),'-',substring($p_str,5,2),'-',substring($p_str,7,2))"/>
<xsl:sequence select="$dt castable as xs:dateTime"/>
```